# 1-Stroke to Jump to Top of Page

Tags: macbook

I've been using a Chrome extension to jump to the top of a webpage, but it started causing problems. I've deleted it, but I really miss being able to hit ONE key to jump to the top. I know the usual shortcuts for my Mac, but I still haven't found the single-key trick. Help, please?

Comment: Have you tried Cmd+Up?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure unless you're willing to spare the small expense of pressing <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>, there's no real option apart from using an external keyboard. I'm  sure that you could delve deep into the built in keyboard driver and find something, but it's likely to disrupt other apps if you remap <kbd>Home</kbd>.

Comment: "Spare the small expense of pressing...." No need to get snippy. I asked a simple question. I'm sure there are shortcuts that you'd miss if you no longer had them.

Comment: That wasn't a dig - perhaps it was badly worded.